# How can I retrieve all checkboxes checked and show in results table?

Tags: jquery, forms

need help over here ;)

I'm working in a form and having a hard time trying to get all checked checkboxes to show in a table row. The way the form is supposed to work is to show all the choices made before you get the option to print your results. The form is broken down in a series of steps, basically all steps divs are hidden and displayed after clicking next.
I think the problem with showing all the checked checkboxes is that I'm using a switch case to move to the next step as you can see in the JS/Jquery code:

```
var valcheck = $('input:checkbox[name=path-school]:checked').val();

                switch (valcheck)
                {
                case 'college':
                  $('#step2-1').slideUp();
                  $('#step3').slideDown();
                  break;
                case 'job':
                    $('#step2-1').slideUp();
                  $('#step3').slideDown();
                  break;
                case 'best':
                $('#step2-1').slideUp();
                  $('#step3').slideDown();
                  break;
                case 'grades':
                $('#step2-1').slideUp();
                 $('#step3').slideDown();
                  break;

                }
```

See below the code I got so far, and also a demo of the form here http://codeplay.pancakeapps.com/

HTML

```
    <!-- #step1 -->
    <div id="step1">
        <h1>Step 1</h1>

        <div class="form">
            <h2>Where do I want to go? (select one)</h2>

            <label class="val" style="width:250px;color:red;"></label><br> 
                <input type="radio" id="school" name="path" value="school" /> School <br>
                <input type="radio" id="home" name="path" value="home" /> Home <br> 
                <input type="radio" id="friends" name="path" value="friends" /> Friends <br>
                <input type="radio" id="activities" name="path" value="activities" /> Activities <br>
                <input type="radio" id="health" name="path" value="health" /> Health <br>
            </div>      
            <div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit_first" id="submit_first" value="">Next</button>
        </div>   
        <div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->

        <!-- #step2-1 -->
        <div id="step2-1">
            <h1>Step 2-1</h1>
            <div class="form">
            <label class="val2" style="width:250px;color:red;"></label><br> 
                <div id="cbox21">
                    <input type="checkbox"  name="path-school" value="college" /> College <br>
                    <input type="checkbox"  name="path-school" value="job" /> Job <br> 
                    <input type="checkbox"  name="path-school" value="best" /> Best <br>
                    <input type="checkbox"  name="path-school" value="grades" /> Grades <br>
                <!-- <input type="text"  id="personal" name="path-school" value="personal" placeholder="type what you want" /> -->
                </div>    

            </div>      
            <div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit2-1" id="submit2-1" value="">Next</button>
        </div>      
        <div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
        <!-- end #step2-1 -->

        <!-- #step3 -->
        <div id="step3">
            <h1>Step 3-1</h1>

            <div class="form">
                <select id="age" name="age">
                    <option> 0 - 17</option>
                    <option>18 - 25</option>
                    <option>26 - 40</option>
                    <option>40+</option>
                </select>
                <label for="age">Your age range. </label> 
                <div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->

                <select id="gender" name="gender">
                    <option>Male</option>
                    <option>Female</option>
                </select>
                <label for="gender">Your Gender. </label> 
                <div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->

                <select id="country" name="country">
                    <option>United States</option>
                    <option>United Kingdom</option>
                    <option>Canada</option>
                    <option>Serbia</option>
                    <option>Italy</option>
                </select>
                <label for="country">Your country. </label> 
                <div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->

            </div>      
            <div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit_third" id="submit_third" value="">Next</button>

        </div>      
        <div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->

        <!-- #step4 -->
        <div id="step4">
            <h1>Step 4</h1>
            <div class="form">
                <h2>Here is your roadmap!</h2>

                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <!-- <tr><td>Username</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Password</td><td></td></tr> -->
                    <tr><td>Path</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Path-school</td><td></td></tr>
                    <!-- <tr><td>Email</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Name</td><td></td></tr> -->
                    <tr><td>Age</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Gender</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Country</td><td></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit_first" id="submit_first" value=""onclick="window.print()">Print roadmap</button>            
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
<div id="progress_bar">
    <div id="progress"></div>
    <div id="progress_text">0% Complete</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner, input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner { border : none; } 
input[type="submit"]:focus, input[type="button"]:focus { outline : none; }

.clear { clear: both; }
#step1-1 {
background-color: orange;
width: 754px;
height: 370px;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 50px 0;
/*overflow: hidden;*/
position: relative;
}
#step1-2 {
background-color: green;
width: 754px;
height: 370px;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 50px 0;
/*overflow: hidden;*/
position: relative;
}
#step1-3 {
background-color: red;
width: 754px;
height: 370px;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 50px 0;
/*overflow: hidden;*/
position: relative;
}
#step1-4 {
background-color: #CCC;
width: 754px;
height: 370px;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 50px 0;
/*overflow: hidden;*/
position: relative;
}
#step1-5 {
background-color: #06C;
width: 754px;
height: 370px;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 50px 0;
/*overflow: hidden;*/
position: relative;
}
#step2-1 {
width: 754px;
height: 370px;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 50px 0;
/*overflow: hidden;*/
position: relative;
}
.container-decisions {
/*background: url('../images/container.png') no-repeat;*/
width: 754px;
height: 370px;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 50px 0;
/*overflow: hidden;*/
position: relative;
 }
 .container-decisions #step1, #step2, #step3, #step4, #step1-1,#step1-2,#step1-3,       #step1-4, #step1-5,
 #step2-1,#step2-2,#step2-3,#step2-4,#step2-5 { 
  display: none; 
   }
  .container-decisions #step1 { display: block; }
  .container-decisions .form { margin: 66px 72px 0 72px; }
  .container-decisions h1 span { color: #06C; }

  .container-decisions h2 {
    color: #888;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: none;
 }

 .container-decisions table {
    margin: 20px 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: solid #CCC 1px;
 }
    .container-decisions table td {
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }
        .container-decisions table td:nth-child(2) {
            font-weight: normal;
        }   

  .container-decisions select {
    background: url('../images/input.png') no-repeat;
    color: #888;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-family: Cantarell, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    float: left;

    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  }

    .container-decisions input.submit:focus { border: none; }
    .container-decisions input.send{ background: url('../images/print.png') no-repeat;}  
    .container-decisions input.error { border: 1px solid red; color:red;}
    .container-decisions input.valid { border: 1px solid #1FFF00; }
    .container-decisions select { padding: 5px 0 5px 25px; }
    .container-decisions option { padding: 0 15px; }

 #progress_bar {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  width: 339px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
 }

 #progress {
  background-color: #D2D2D2;
  width: 0px;
  height: 14px;

  border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  }
 #progress_text {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #06C;
  width: 339px;
  height: 24px;
  top: -36px;
  left: 0;
 }
```

JS/JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//original field values
var field_values = {
        //id        :  value
        'school'    : 'destination', 
        'home'      : 'destination',
        'friends'   : 'destination',
        'activities': 'destination',
        'health'    : 'destination',
        'username'  : 'username',
        'password'  : 'password',
        'cpassword' : 'password',
        'firstname' : 'first name',
        'lastname'  : 'last name',
        'email'     : 'email address',
        'job-pays'  : 'job-pays'
    };


//inputfocus
$('input#job-pays').inputfocus({ value: field_values['job-pays'] });
$('input#username').inputfocus({ value: field_values['username'] });
$('input#password').inputfocus({ value: field_values['password'] });
$('input#cpassword').inputfocus({ value: field_values['cpassword'] }); 
$('input#lastname').inputfocus({ value: field_values['lastname'] });
$('input#firstname').inputfocus({ value: field_values['firstname'] });
$('input#email').inputfocus({ value: field_values['email'] }); 

//reset progress bar
$('#progress').css('width','0');
$('#progress_text').html('0% Complete');
$('.val').hide();
//step1
$('form').submit(function(){ return false; });
$('#submit_first').click(function(){
    //remove classes
    //$('#step1 input').removeClass('error').removeClass('valid');

    //ckeck if inputs aren't empty
    var path=$ ('#path').val();
    if ($('input:radio[name=path]:checked') .length == 0){
        $('.val').fadeIn(2000) .html('<span>Please select one</span>');
        $('#step1').effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);
        return false;
    } 

            //update progress bar
            $('#progress_text').html('33% Complete');
            $('#progress').css('width','113px');

            //slide steps
            var valrad = $('input:radio[name=path]:checked').val();

                switch (valrad)
                {
                case 'school':
                  $('#step1').slideUp();
                  $('#step2-1').slideDown();
                  break;
                case 'home':
                    $('#step1').slideUp();
                  $('#step1-2').slideDown();
                  break;
                case 'friends':
                $('#step1').slideUp();
                  $('#step1-3').slideDown();
                  break;
                case 'activities':
                $('#step1').slideUp();
                 $('#step1-4').slideDown();
                  break;
                case 'health':
                $('#step1').slideUp();
                  $('#step1-5').slideDown();
                  break;
                default:

                }
              });

    $('#submit2-1').click(function(){
    //remove classes
    $('#step2-1 input').removeClass('error').removeClass('valid');

    //ckeck if inputs aren't empty
    var path_school=$ ('#path-school').val();
    if ($('input:checkbox[name=path-school]:checked') .length == 0){
        $('.val2').fadeIn(2000) .html('<span>Please select one</span>');
        $('#step2-1').effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);
        return false;
    } 
            //update progress bar
            $('#progress_text').html('66% Complete');
            $('#progress').css('width','226px');

            //slide steps
            var valcheck = $('input:checkbox[name=path-school]:checked').val();

                switch (valcheck)
                {
                case 'college':
                  $('#step2-1').slideUp();
                  $('#step3').slideDown();
                  break;
                case 'job':
                    $('#step2-1').slideUp();
                  $('#step3').slideDown();
                  break;
                case 'best':
                $('#step2-1').slideUp();
                  $('#step3').slideDown();
                  break;
                case 'grades':
                $('#step2-1').slideUp();
                 $('#step3').slideDown();
                  break;

                }  
        });

    $('#submit_third').click(function(){
    //update progress bar
    $('#progress_text').html('100% Complete');
    $('#progress').css('width','339px');

    //prepare the fourth step
    var fields = new Array(
        $('input:radio[name=path]:checked').val(),
        $('input:checkbox[name=path-school]:checked').val(),

        // $('#email').val(),
        // $('#firstname').val() + ' ' + $('#lastname').val(),
        $('#age').val(),
        $('#gender').val(),
        $('#country').val()                       
        );
    var tr = $('#step4 tr');
    tr.each(function(){
        //alert( fields[$(this).index()] )
        $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').html(fields[$(this).index()]);
    });

    //slide steps
    $('#step3').slideUp();
    $('#step4').slideDown();            
    });

   $('#submit_fourth').click(function(){
    //send information to server
    alert('Data sent');
   });

   });
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your first step returns values which are missing in the shown switch statement. I.e. school, home, friends etc ... are missed. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: Krasimir, there is another switch statement for that and works fine, because you can only check one radio button at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple values on checkboxes so try.

```
var arr;
$('input:checkbox[name=path-school]:checked').each(function () {
  arr.push($(this).val());
});
```

Then go through the array and add the values to step 4.

Comment: will it be easier if I give them the same value?

Comment: No, checkboxes are designed to have multiple values. If not, use radioboxes.